Why is the generated hash from a just downloaded stream is different than the one generated when I close and reopen the stream?
I'm currently downloading a .zip file from S3 and I have to compare the local file with the S3 file when the download is complete.
I'm doing that applying a SHA1 hash algorithm and comparing the generated hash with a hash also in S3.
The thing is, when I generate the hash with the stream from the download, I get a different hash than if I close the stream and then create a new one of the same zip file.
Why is that?
I know how to correct my problem, but I want to know why it happens.

What value has the Position property of the first stream before you pass it to SHA1? It should be 0.
